# Remove and add new JLabel in mouseListener

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, mouselistener

I have 2 `JLabels`, and I add `MouseListener` to one of them,which can remove other `JLabel` and draw it again(when I click on one of them,the `Image` of other one change)
this is my code,but it does't work,it remove `JLabel`,but don't paint it again,what should I do?

```
ImageIcon icon_next = new ImageIcon("next-icon.PNG");
...
next = new JLabel(icon_next);
...
next.addMouseListener(this);
player_img_lbl = new JLabel(player_img_ico[0]);
add(player_img_lbl, FlowLayout.CENTER);
....
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        this.remove(player_img_lbl);
    JLabel player_img_lbl = new JLabel(player_img_ico[1]);
    add(player_img_lbl0,FlowLayout.CENTER);
    repaint();
}
```

is there another way exist ,which when I click on one of the `JLabel`,it can change `Image` of other one?

Comment: player_img_lbl is being used as a field AND as a local variable. This is not a good idea.

Comment: My question is, why do you want to remove the label?

You can set the visibility to false, or update the content of a label inside the listener action. For these you do not have to remove the label. Removing and adding could break the layout, which will confuse the user.

Answer (score 4):

Call revalidate() before repaint()

Comment: @StanislavL : Please edit the answer as MoeinHm suggested to you. Else, people reading through this fastly and not looking in the comment section wont see the right solution.

Comment: @user7185318 actually revalidate() includes validate() so my answer is correct. In some cases validate() is enough but it's better to call revalidate() to be sure

Comment: @StanislavL : Sorry, I didnt knew this.